# How to pass a string as an argument for a thread in C

Tags: c, pthreads

I'm new to C and programming and I'm trying to pass a string into a thread so that I manipulate it later. I've tried creating string using an array `char string[] = "word"` and passing it to the thread - now a pointer `char *word = "word"` with no luck. How do I pass a string as an argument into a thread??

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> // exit calls
#include <pthread.h> // contains thread package

void *print_string_in_reverse_order(void *str)
{
    char *string = (char *)str;
    printf("%s\n", *string); // this won't print anything

    pthread_exit(NULL); // exit the thread
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    pthread_t threadID;
    char *word = "word"; //should this be an array?
    printf("In function main(): Creating a new thread\n");

    // create a new thread in the calling process
    int status = pthread_create(&threadID, NULL, print_string_in_reverse_order, (void *)&word);

}
```

Comment: Use `(void *)word`. The address of `word` is the address of the pointer, which is **not** the address of the string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You problem is that you are passing the pointer to a pointer to the string when you use `&word` you need to use just `word` in your `pthread_create` argument.

This is becuase when you declare

```
const char* word = "my word";
```

memory for "my world" is allocated in read only global memory and a `word` then becomes a pointer to that memory on the stack. Be aware even when not declaring `word` as const you cannot modify the string.

```
const char word[] = "my word";
```

creates an array big for "my word". This is normally not safe to pass to another thread since the memory gets deleted then the stack unwinds at the end of your function.

The simplest safe way to declare a modifiable string will be to declare somthing like:

```
static char word[] = "my word";
```

which will guarantee that "my word" is in global memory and will definitely be available, otherwise you will need to allocate memory using `malloc`

Answer (score 1):

1. `pthread_create(...., (void *)&word);`

You pass an address to a pointer. `&word` has the type `char**` - it's a pointer to pointer to `char`. So you can either get it as a `char**` and then dereference the pointer (and also make sure that the address `&word` is valid for the other thread execution) or just pass `word` instead as you probably meant to do.

2. `printf("%s\n", *string);` - `*string` is a `char`, not a `char*`. `%s` expends a pointer to a zero terminated array of characters with type `char*`. Enable compiler warnings and listen to them - compiler should warn about such mistakes.
3. You have to join your thread before you exit your program. Because `main` exits right after `pthread_create`, your program exits, the other thread also exits. Because the second thread doesn't get enough cpu time to execute the `printf` statement, nothing get's printed out (if the rest of the code would be valid..

So probably you want to:

```
void *print_string_in_reverse_order(void *str) {
    char *string = str;
    printf("%s\n", string);
    return NULL;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    pthread_t threadID;
    const char *word = "word"; // string literals are immutable
    printf("In function main(): Creating a new thread\n");
    int status = pthread_create(&threadID, NULL, print_string_in_reverse_order, word);
    pthread_join(threadID, NULL);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the information - that worked for me.